# Finding the null rate of the column device_id

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I'm trying to write a code that will display the null count for a column in a table

I wrote the code below but i've been running into a syntax issue

```
SELECT device_id AS FIELD, COUNT (*)
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM TABLE
      WHERE TRIM(UPPER(device_id) IN ('','NULL',) OR device_id IS NULL OR SUBSTRING(TRIM(UPPER(device_id)), 1,1) = '-') 
AND (event_date between '2019-05-20' AND '2019-05-27')
     );
```

I've been experiencing a syntax error

> cannot recognize input near ')' 'OR' 'device_id' in expression
>   specification:17:16,

Comment: And what is the syntax error message that you have been receiving?

Comment: cannot recognize input near ')' 'OR' 'device_id' in expression specification:17:16,

Comment: That would have been better placed in the question

Comment: You're right. I apologize for that

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL at least, subqueries require an alias.  But you don't need a subquery.  So I think you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM <TABLE> t
WHERE (TRIM(UPPER(device_id)) IN ('', 'NULL') OR
       device_id IS NULL OR
       TRIM(UPPER(device_id)) LIKE '-%')
      ) AND
      event_date between '2019-05-20' AND '2019-05-27';
```

Notes:

- You had a trailing comma in the `IN list.
- I don't think you had the write parentheses before the `event_date` comparison.
- You cannot include `device_id` in the `SELECT` unless you have `GROUP BY`, but I think you just want the count.
- `LIKE` is much easier than `SUBSTRING()` for your third comparison.
- All the `TRIM()`s and `UPPER()`s suggest that you should maintain better control of your data.  These should not be necessary, particularly in an "id" column.

Comment: I got this error when i tried your code Wrong arguments ''-%'': trim takes only STRING/CHAR/VARCHAR types.

Comment: The `TRIM` parenthesis is not properly closed on the line `WHERE (TRIM(UPPER(device_id) IN ('', 'NULL') OR`, and you can remove the closing parenthesis on the `) AND` line